# Javascript RegEx not matching as expected

Tags: javascript, regex

I have some code that looks like this:

```js
// searchTerm is input by the user
// I am escaping especial characters as described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/6969486
let searchTerm = '1054';
var regex = new RegExp(searchTerm, 'gi');

let data = [
    { id: '10545' },
    { id: '10544' },
    { id: '10543' },
    { id: '10542' },
    { id: '10541' }
];

let result = data.filter(
    row => regex.test(row.id)
);

console.log(result);
```

And here is the result in the console:

```
[
    { id:"10545" },
    { id:"10543" },
    { id:"10541" }
]
```

I was expecting it to match all five IDs. Why does it match only three? How can I make it match all five?

Thank you.

Comment: Remove the `g` modifier.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew can you post it as an answer so that I can mark it as the selected answer?

Comment: The `g` modifier is never needed if you're just testing with the regexp. It's useful when replacing or returning the matches.

Comment: @ArepaSlayer He already closed the question as a duplicate of a question that has the answer.

Comment: Thank you all. Appreciate the quick responses.